# 'No such file or directory' error in bash, but the file exists?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, android

On Ubuntu, I get a 'No such file or directory' error when I try to execute a command.

I have checked with `ls -la` , the file  `adb` is there and it has 'x' flag
So why I am getting a 'No such file or directory'?

```
~/Programs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools$ ./adb
 bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
~/Programs/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools$ ls -la
 total 34120
 drwxrwxr-x 3 silverstri silverstri     4096 2011-10-08 18:50 .
 drwxrwxr-x 8 silverstri silverstri     4096 2011-10-08 18:51 ..
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri  3764858 2011-10-08 18:50 aapt
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri   366661 2011-10-08 18:50 adb
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri   906346 2011-10-08 18:50 aidl
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri   328445 2011-10-08 18:50 dexdump
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri     2603 2011-10-08 18:50 dx
 drwxrwxr-x 2 silverstri silverstri     4096 2011-10-08 18:50 lib
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri 14269620 2011-10-08 18:50 llvm-rs-cc
 -rwxrwxr-x 1 silverstri silverstri 14929076 2011-10-08 18:50 llvm-rs-cc-2
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 silverstri silverstri      241 2011-10-08 18:50 llvm-rs-cc.txt
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 silverstri silverstri   332494 2011-10-08 18:50 NOTICE.txt
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 silverstri silverstri      291 2011-10-08 18:50 source.properties
```

Comment: what do you get if you run `file adb`

Comment: i get this '$ file adb
adb: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped
'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an executable file that misses required libraries. Use `ldd` to see what it needs, then provide these files.

Comment: i get this '$ ldd ./adb
 not a dynamic executable'

Answer (score 54):

Android SDK requires 32-bit libraries. You probably are on 64-bit and need the 32-bit libs. Here are the troubleshooting directions from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)

For Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and above, install the `libncurses5:i386`, `libstdc++6:i386`, and `zlib1g:i386` packages using apt-get:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

For earlier versions of Ubuntu, install the `ia32-libs` package using apt-get:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: damn that installs a lot of stuff. But it works.

Comment: Like michael, "file" told me it was a 32 bit ELF binary and ldd told me it was not a dynamic executable. Installing these 32 bit libraries fixed the problem.

Comment: Most misleading error message EVER! o_O

Comment: re:{Here are the troubleshooting directions from developer.android.com} I don't see any troubleshooting directions there...

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
```

is also need for me.

Comment: Did you mean that helped? Any idea why? Where did you get this from?

Answer (score 3):

I was also seeing the same after switching my machine from 32 bit ubuntu to 64 bit. Bash would report 'No such file or directory' of files that clearly existed with the execute attribute.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386

Fixed the problem. These are the "GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64"

Seems like this is a bug in bash. Note that I also changed the default shell from dash to bash using

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash

before I tried running the 32 bit executable. So I'm not sure if the problem would have happened with the default dash shell

Answer (score 2):

On a fresh Xubuntu 13.10 x64 install I got `adb` to run with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
```

And also `zlib1g:i386` to make `aapt` work.

and if you still miss something use:

```
lld adb
```

Comment: This worked great for me, but I had to call `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; sudo apt-get update` to make libstdc++6:i386 available

Comment: I think you meant `ldd adb`

Answer (score 1):

For adb make sure you have the SDK unpacked and have run the SDK Manager to fully populate the SDK. Additionally make sure you have the following installed:
A.) JDK 6 or better
B.) lib32stdc++6
C.) lib32ncurses5

hoffmanc was the closest to getting it right, I don't really understand why the answer from Daniel Beck is marked as correct when it's not even close and has nothing to do with the problem.

Incidentally, if you try to run a truly non-existant command (i.e.:

```
# fakecommand
```

you'll get: fakecommand: command not found, whereas in your situation the output you are seeing is actually coming from adb even though it's not very clear that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

*Ubuntu* seems to have some issues with LSB compatibility, so try this if you are on *Ubuntu*:

```
apt-get install lsb
```

Note that ldd will sort of show that all the libraries are there, but they are not.

```
usmp-vm-lamp01$ ldd lmgrd
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb33fe000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f10b0a48000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f10b074c000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f10b0535000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f10b0175000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f10aff71000)
 /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10b0c67000)
usmp-vm-lamp01$ locate libpthread.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
usmp-vm-lamp01$ locate libm.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
usmp-vm-lamp01$ locate /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
usmp-vm-lamp01$
```

Comment: I was having this problem with a speech recognition package called Julius.  This is what fixed it for me.