# Running commands and shell scripts in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to run a shell script in Ubuntu to flash my Firefox OS phone.  I've downloaded and unzipped the new version.  I've launched the shell and navigated to the directory where the `.sh` file is.

All of the files required to flash the phone are in the same directory.  It uses two executables - `adb` and `flashboot` - which are both in the that directory.  I type in `./flash.sh` and it produces the output 'no such file or directory' errors.

I've typed in `./adb` (which is the first command in the shell script) and it gives the same error - even though I can see the executable is there.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure it is something simple.

#### EDIT #1

Here is the `ls` output for the `adb` executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 parallels parallels    204436 Jun 13 18:41 adb
```

Yes, I'm definitely in the right directory

```
parallels@~/Downloads$ pwd    
/home/parallels/Downloads
```

Full `ls -la`:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 parallels parallels      4096 Sep  8 13:17 .  
drwxr-xr-x 39 parallels parallels      4096 Sep  8 13:16 ..  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 parallels parallels    204436 Jun 13 18:41 adb  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels    191488 Jun 13 18:41 adb.exe  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels     96256 Jun 13 18:41 AdbWinApi.dll  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels     60928 Jun 13 18:41 AdbWinUsbApi.dll  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels   4923392 Jun 13 18:41 boot.img  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 parallels parallels    149928 Jun 13 18:41 fastboot  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels    140800 Jun 13 18:41 fastboot.exe  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels      1044 Jun 13 18:41 flash.bat  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 parallels parallels       170 Jun 13 18:41 flash_mac.sh  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 parallels parallels       182 Jun 13 18:41 flash.sh  
-rw-rw-r--  1 parallels parallels  99863338 Sep  7 22:57 images-peak-2013-06-13.Gecko-86f00ac.Gaia-619c980.zip  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels 153211752 Jun 13 18:41 system.img  
-rw-r--r--  1 parallels parallels  33649328 Jun 13 18:41 userdata.img
```

This is what I get trying to execute `adb`. (I've created a new directory 'flash' to make sure it is not specific to the Downloads directory):

```
parallels@~/flash$ ./adb
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

#### EDIT #2

Found this:

- ['No such file or directory' error in bash, but the file exists?](https://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists)

Looks like it might be the same thing.  Something to do with the executables being 32 bit on a 64 bit system and therefore required libs are missing.

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right directory? Can you show us the output of `ls -la`?

Comment: Are you sure they have (x - executable) mod on the files? Try chmod +x ./adb and then run it again? (and maybe need to run as sudo)

Comment: @Darius If there weren't appropriate execute permissions, the OP would have gotten a *permission denied* error, not a *no such file* one.

Comment: Just to be sure: It says './adb: No such file or directory'?

Comment: @Tim yes, thats what it says.parallels@~/flash$ ./adb  
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you try the suggestions from the question you linked to?

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to run a Windows executable. Try wine adb.exe.

Comment: He appears to be trying to run the adb file, not the adb.exe file.